# Limit text size in GridView column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an **asp:GridView** declared as follows:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="dg_myprojects" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="900px" CssClass="Grid" OnSorting="TaskGridView_SortingMine" OnRowCommand="MyProjectList_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="project_id" OnRowDataBound="Ds_my_projects_RowDataBound">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alternateRow" />
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeader" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="project_name" HeaderText="Project Name" SortExpression="project_name"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="description" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="role" HeaderText="Role" SortExpression="role" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="start_date" HeaderText="Start Date" SortExpression="start_date" DataFormatString="{0:d}"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="end_date" HeaderText="End Date" SortExpression="end_date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="client" HeaderText="Client" SortExpression="client" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("project_id") %>' CommandName="Remove" runat="server">Remove</asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="project_id" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="EditProject.aspx?pID={0}" Text="Edit"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My problem is100% aesthetic. The word wrap that happens for long descriptions make the table look tacky. What I want to do with a long description is have an ellipses (...) when the description gets too long

> Long description blah blah...

I couldn't find a built in method for this so I decided to try to implement this `OnRowDataBound` of the GridView.

```
protected void Ds_my_projects_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{            
   DataRow curRow = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
  if (curRow["Description"].ToString().Length > 200)
       curRow["Description"] = curRow["Description"].ToString().Substring(0, 200) + "...";

}
```

I get an run time exception on the first line because of **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a simpler way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I don't think there is any inbuilt method for it, they way you are doing is right.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could handle it with css and by adding this to your `Grid` css class:

```
.Grid {
    table-layout:fixed; 
    width:100%; 
}
.Grid .Shorter {
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    white-space: nowrap;        
}
```

**Update**: I modified the above class so that you can affect an individual column by using the ItemStyle-CssClass attribute like so:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Description" 
    SortExpression="description" ItemStyle-CssClass="Shorter" />
```

Comment: Works great. Unfortunately the table-layout:fixed sets all my column widths to the same but I'll find a workaround

Comment: Thank you. This is a great solution but what if I wanted to do something where on hover it displays all the text?

Answer (score 7):

What I would do is create an Extension class that can shorten strings.  The static class would have something like the following method:

```
public static string Shorten(this string name, int chars)
{
    if (name.ToCharArray().Count() > chars)
    {
        return name.Substring(0, chars) + "...";
    }
    else return name;
}
```

You could then use the BoundFields as TemplateFields like so:

```
<asp:TemplateField> 
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" Text="<%# Eval("description").ToString().Shorten(20) %>" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The nice thing about this is that you could now use the `Shorten()` method anywhere.

Comment: +1 for a great solution that can be applied anywhere this is needed. Extension methods are so handy when used right!

Comment: `runat="server"` is missing from Label tag

Answer (score 2):

CAbbot has a great suggestion. I've never done it this way but if that works for you, then I like that; simple, elegant, efficient.

The way I've always done it has been through through the DataSource. If you are binding a `SqlDataSource` to your `GridView`, you could do a select query like this:

```
DECLARE @temp NVARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @maxLength INT;
SET @temp = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
SET @maxLength = 10;

SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(@temp) > @maxLength THEN SUBSTRING(@temp, 0, @maxLength) + '...' ELSE @temp END
```

As far as fixing the issue at hand with your `RowDataBound`, that should work too. But you shouldn't need to do the casting, try this instead:

```
protected void Ds_my_projects_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.Cells[1].Text.ToString().Length > 200)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = e.Row.Cells[1].Text.ToString().Substring(0, 200) + "...";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple and effective. I probably won't change my procedure but the changing the text on rowdatabound works for me

Answer (score 1):

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="description" >
    <ItemTemplate >
      <%# Eval("description").ToString().Length>100? (Eval("description") as string).Substring(0,100)+"..." : Eval("description")  %> 
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

GridView's Column Remark in Template Field shown as "Remark ..." and Tooltip will show as full text.

```
 <ItemTemplate>    <asp:Label ID="lblRemark" runat="server" 
                   Text= '<%# Eval("Remark").ToString().Length > 6? (Eval("Remark") as string).Substring(0,6) + " ..." : Eval("Remark")  %>'
                   tooltip = '<%# Eval("Remark") %> '> </asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and it worked fine.
Add the following code to your .aspx page :

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Body" ItemStyle-Width="900px">
            <ItemTemplate >
                <%#Eval("Body").ToString().Length > 125 ? (Eval("Body").ToString().Substring(0,125))+"........": Eval("Body") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```