# Sub String code not working in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written below line of code:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDetail" runat="server" Text='<%#_14Communities.Web.CODEFILES.SECUREFILES.WebUtility.LimitString(Server.HtmlDecode((string)Eval("Purpose")).ToString().Replace("\n","<br/>"),200) %>'></asp:Label>
```

Now I want to display only 200 characters. It is not working.

Comment: Please supply a better description of what goes wrong. is it in ASP or C#? what actually happens, and is there an error message or an exception?

Comment: it might help you refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7651192/795683

Comment: Check LimitString obviously it is not working

Comment: What does `_14Communities.Web.CODEFILES.SECUREFILES.WebUtility.LimitString` method do? Can you provide the code of that method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple intrinsic dotNet function `substring`

```
yourString.Substring(0, 200);
```